# Convert white parts in image to transparent to simulate printing

Tags: php, printing, imagemagick, rgba, cmyk

I am currently developing an AJAX application using PHP and Javascript that allows people to upload images that will be printed on foil. Since I will be using a standard CMYK printer, it won't print any white parts, but rather just leave those spots blank - a thing that usually does not make a difference on white paper, but here it does, since I'm printing on foil. It gets more complicated when you consider that a grey dot will become semi-transparent black, and I'm not even talking of colors yet.

Yet I would like to create a PNG file with an alpha channel that will simulate the printing process, so I can give a preview of how the printed foil would look when being hold against different backgrounds.

Now I do understand the basic theory of subtractive and additive color models and also of RGBA and CMYK, but then again it's only the basics and here I'm kind of at a loss of how to proceed. I guess in theory you would convert every pixel into CMYK and interpret each channel as a scale from transparent to color instead of from white to color, but how would you translate that back into RGBA?

The nicest thing would, of course, be if ImageMagick would provide such a feature .... does it, or do I have to loop through the pixels manually? If the latter, how would I do the calculations?

I don't know if this has been an issue before. I couldn't find anything on either Stackoverflow or Google, but maybe I just missed the right keywords. Any further reading, food for thoughts or hyperlinks with a note "we discussed this a million times, idiot!" would be warmly welcome.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

What you basically want is to add an alpha channel to the uploaded image and create a PNG file.

The alpha channel should represent the opacity of the printed color. To generate it, you have several options:

1. Take a copy of the image, convert it to grayscale, invert it and use it as alpha channel.
2. Create an alpha channel compute the alpha value of each pixel derived from the original image as: *alpha = 1.0 - min(red, green, blue)* (use 255 instead of 1.0 depending on whether you're using integer or floating point numbers).
3. Convert the original image to CMYK (using a color profile and not the poor formulas youn find all over the internet) and use it as the basis to create the alpha channel for the original RGB image: *alpha = max(cyan, magenta, yellow, black)*.
4. Come up with an even better formula to compute the transparency of each pixel such as: alpha = min(0.2 * cyan + 0.5 * magenta + 0.1 * yellow + 0.7 * black, 1.0)

The last one is just a guess of the relative opacity of each color. You can certainly improve it.

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot. That's 4 fantastic solutions right for the part where I got stuck. Especially the first one strikes me as very intriguing because of its simplicity and elegance. And given that we are only talking of print previews here, I think the results will be prefect for the needs. I will try them and let you know hot it worked.

Comment: Remark: Variant 1 works, but it will make your colors look pale. This is why I added a part to adjust the levels of the mask image. My batch script right now looks like this: `convert a.png -colorspace Gray -negate -level-colors black,"#aaaaaa" b.png` and `convert a.png b.png -alpha Off -compose CopyOpacity -composite c.png`. This gives me pretty good results for the moment, but probably on the long run I might change to variant 3 to get more accurate results.